# Migrating classic VM to Resource manager

Tags: azure

Is it possible to Migrate a classic Azure VM to the new Azure Resources Manager? If so how?

I had been trying a lot, searched on various websites but could not find the correct answer. There is in fact no article also from MSDN. Please help.

Comment: There's an [Azure Blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transitioning-to-the-resource-manager-model/) with [scripts](https://github.com/fullscale180/asm2arm) only a google search away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to migrate VM's from classic to resource manager.
Follow the steps:

1. Create a classic storage account in the location were you want your vm.
2. Take note of the existing storage account for the RM VM(this will be your source in Powershell script).
3. Download the Azure Storage Copy Tools(AzCopy.exe)
4. From powershell, change path to the AzCopy folder(C:\ 'Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy')
5. run the command:  .\AzCopy /Source:…….. /Dest:……… /SourceKey:…………. /DestKey…. /Pattern:………… where source and dest are your storage account names(url only till contianer name) and Pattern is name of your source OS disk.(abc.vhd)
6. after running this command, go to manage portal and from disks create new disk by choosing the vhd container(dest storage account vhd container).
7. create VM from the OS disk.
   Note: Stop the VM (source) when running AzCopy command.